# How to set up pagination dynamically in ant design table

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have an ant design Table, and a request to the server that receives users by page, how can I make the total count ant design pagination based not on the array of transferred users to table, but on the total count number. That is, how to flexibly configure pagination in the ant design table (dynamic pagination)

Comment: Could you replicate your code at codesandbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Table` have a prop [Pagination](https://ant.design/components/pagination/), you can use it to set the total to the value you want.

You can base your tests with the [Ajax demo](https://ant.design/components/table/#components-table-demo-pagination) in the documentation.

**To resume it looks like this:**

```
function Component() {
  const [pagination, setPagination] = useState({});

  function handleTableChange() {

     requestToServer().then((data) => {
       pagination.total = your_value;
       setPagination(pagination);
     }) 
  }
  return (
   <Table
      otherprops
      pagination={pagination}
      onChange={handleTableChange}
   />
  )
}
```